# Can we Translate english into hindi?

Tags: android, translation

I want to translate english to hindi but emualtor shows boxes ?
help me...

```
final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    textV.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"K010.ttf")); 
    try{
    Translate.setHttpReferrer("www.some.com");
    String str1=Translate.execute("love", Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
    textV.setText(str1);
```

still i am getting boxes.....help me

Comment: you can refer to this [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/api/translate/TranslatorFrame.java)

Comment: @Uttam this won't help, Android platform doesn't support Hindi fonts on their device

Comment: i just put hindi font in asset folder ,why it is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Emulator shows boxes...may mean that the required font support is not present on your machine...please check if the Hindi font has been installed...
But I did not understand the need for you to use the webView.loadDataWithBaseURL()...this would not do the translation I think...This will just try to load the given data into the WebView...and may be as the Hindi font is not supported the boxes are being displayed...

Are you developing kind of translator application or web page?
where you type English in one TextView and select the langauge to which it has to be translated and the press an buttons "Translate"...and the translated string will be displayed in other TextView...

Comment: Thank for your reply,if i supposed to do developing multiple languages(not supported by emulator) then what i should i do? Download all fonts? Is there any solution ?

Comment: I believe yes...you will need the fonts to support the specific language for which you need to develop...